# Access 2013 VBA Editor Changes Date() to date

Tags: ms-access, vba

When I type `strDate = Date()` it switches to `strDate = date`, and then the code does not run correctly because it does not know what "date" refers to.  This is in a brand new Access 2013 database with only a single form with a button to run the code and a table with only one field to insert the date.

References that are checked for this database are:

- Visual Basic For Applications
- Microsoft Access 15.0 Object Library
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft Office 15.0 Access database engine Object Library

  ```
  Dim strDate As String
  strDate = Date()

  DoCmd.SetWarnings False

  Dim strSQL As String
  strSQL = "INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('" & strDate & "');"
  DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

  DoCmd.SetWarnings True
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are inserting a date value into your table, the value should **not** be enclosed with single quotes, else the data will be interpreted as a string.

Similarly, the `Date` function will return a date value, hence your variable `strDate` should be of type `Date` as opposed to `String`.

The automatic conversion of `Date()` to `Date` is to be expected and will still result in the `Date` function being evaluated with no arguments; I believe this conversion occurs because the symbol `Date` also corresponds to a data type.

However, an easier way to achieve this is to simply evaluate the `Date` function directly in the SQL code, for example:

```vb
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (Date());"
```

Comment: Thank you.  This database was a simplified experiment/test.  My company uses a database that runs a backup when it is run for the first time on a given day.  It is a bi-coastal company, and our folks on the West coast have been upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10, and they get errors on start up:  "Function is not available in expressions in query expression 'BackupDate = date('."  There was another error that also referenced the date function.  Here on the East coast we are still on Windows 7 for now.  I created the above to test the date function in Windows 10.  Still inconclusive.

Comment: @sruhs007 That info must be added to question, as it leads us to a broken reference. Check on Win10 if some are marked`missing`! Office versions are the same?